# Fluentd - "incoming chunk is broken"

Tags: logging, fluentd

I run fluentd image on docker container. When I open TCP connection with telnet (or netcat) and send "message" string, following message occurs:

```
2017-01-24 10:22:00 +0000 [warn]: incoming chunk is broken: source="host: 192.168.99.1, 
addr: 192.168.99.1, port: 12345" msg=109

2017-01-24 10:22:00 +0000 [warn]: incoming chunk is broken: source="host: 192.168.99.1, 
addr: 192.168.99.1, port: 12345" msg=101

2017-01-24 10:22:00 +0000 [warn]: incoming chunk is broken: source="host: 192.168.99.1, 
addr: 192.168.99.1, port: 12345" msg=115

2017-01-24 10:22:00 +0000 [warn]: incoming chunk is broken: source="host: 192.168.99.1, 
addr: 192.168.99.1, port: 12345" msg=115

2017-01-24 10:22:00 +0000 [warn]: incoming chunk is broken: source="host: 192.168.99.1, 
addr: 192.168.99.1, port: 12345" msg=97

2017-01-24 10:22:00 +0000 [warn]: incoming chunk is broken: source="host: 192.168.99.1, 
addr: 192.168.99.1, port: 12345" msg=103

2017-01-24 10:22:00 +0000 [warn]: incoming chunk is broken: source="host: 192.168.99.1, 
addr: 192.168.99.1, port: 12345" msg=101
```

I don't understand why my "message" is sent character by character and shows up like this in the fluentd side. How can I display my "message" as a whole?

Also, when I send a JSON formatted string, still I get "incoming chunk is broken" warning. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Can you try adding a "-v" on the CMD. So you can get a more verbose output. You can see here how i did: https://github.com/Berndinox/fluentd-pushover/blob/master/Dockerfile

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when using fluent-bit as a client, because of a format mismatch between what was sent and what was expected.

The following solved it for me (both configs need to be set for http):

**fluent-bit.conf**

```
[INPUT]
  name cpu
  tag  cpu.local
  interval_sec 2

[OUTPUT]
  Name  http
  Match *
  Host  12.345.678.9
  Port  1234
  URI   /tagname
  Format json
```

**td-agent.conf**

```
<source>
  @type http
  port 1234
  <parse>
    @type json
  </parse>
</source>

<match tagname>
  @type copy
  <store>
    @type stdout
    @id output_stdout
  </store>
</match>
```