# Why does FluentD in_forward plugin treat JSON object as an Array and log Incoming chunk is broken?

Tags: ruby, tls1.2, fluentd

The code below is executed from a FluentD node in AWS. FluentD warns of **Incoming chunk is broken** [here](https://github.com/fluent/fluentd/blob/master/lib/fluent/plugin/in_forward.rb#L290). The TLS connection is successful. I am using ruby 2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091) [x86_64-linux-gnu]. The payload (msg) is a well-formed JSON object. The payload appears as a JSON string in the FluentD log together with the ruby hash of the object (i.e. : is replaced with =>).

Why does the code below return true for **msg.is_a?(Array)**?

```
begin
    socket = TCPSocket.new(host, port)
    ssl_context = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new()

    rsa_cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(ssl_cert_string)
    rsa_pkey = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(ssl_key_string)
    ca_intermediate_cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(ssl_ca_cert_string)

    ssl_context.add_certificate(rsa_cert, rsa_pkey, [ca_intermediate_cert])

    ssl_context.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
    ssl_context.ssl_version = :TLSv1_2
    ssl_socket = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new(socket, ssl_context)
    ssl_socket.sync_close = true
    ssl_socket.connect
    ssl_socket.puts(msg)
rescue Exception => e
    puts "FluentD exception :#{e.message}"
ensure
    ssl_socket&.close
    socket&.close
end
```

The relevant portion of the fluent.conf is:

```
<source>
  @type forward
  port {{port}}
  bind 0.0.0.0
  <parse>
    @type json
  </parse>
  <transport tls>
    version TLSv1_2
    cert_path {{tls_certificate}}
    private_key_path {{tls_private_key}}
    private_key_passphrase ""
  </transport>
  tag fluentd_ssl
</source>
```

It is used like so:

```
foo = ProgressBar.new(N*M)
start_concurrent = Time.now
N.times.map do
  foo.increment!
  bar = ProgressBar.new(M)
  Thread.new do
    M.times do
      bar.increment!
      send_message(host, port, ssl_ca_cert_string, ssl_cert_string, ssl_key_string)
      sleep 0.1
    end
  end
end.each(&:join)
finish_concurrent = Time.now
duration = humanize(finish_concurrent - start_concurrent)
puts "Concurrent duration: #{duration}"
```

I have tried using ssl_socket.syswrite(msg.to_s) and ssl_socket.write(msg.to_s) thinking that puts method had side-effects but both failed.

I don't know how-to / the best way-to apply the following monkey patch to FluentD (I am new to Ruby) so I can add the custom on_message warning to FluentD logs (I just assume that there is a way).

```
require 'fluent/plugin/in_forward'

module Skylight
  module Probes
    module Fluentd
      module ForwardInput
        def on_message(msg, chunk_size, conn)
          log.warn "on_message: #{msg}"
          super
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

Fluent::Plugin::ForwardInput.include Skylight::Probes::Fluentd::ForwardInput
```

[format mismatch between what was sent and what was expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41822406/fluentd-incoming-chunk-is-broken)

[msgpack's unpacker receives broken msgpack stream from socket](https://github.com/fluent/fluentd/issues/1743)

How can I find out (Ruby or FluentD) why I am getting **Incoming chunk is broken**? Without overriding [on_message](https://github.com/fluent/fluentd/blob/master/lib/fluent/plugin/in_forward.rb#L226).

The entire JSON object appears in the FluentD log so I don't think that it is chunk_size < msg size splitting the msg into an array but I know I'm missing something.

Comment: Added ssl_socket.post_connection_check(host) before ssl_socket.puts(msg). FluentD exception :hostname xxx does not match the server certificate

Comment: `msg.is_a?(Array)` is `false`, not `true`. `unless` checks for `false`. So, `unless msg.is_a?(Array)` is true because `msg` is not an array. Are you able to generate the same issue without the SSL config? Have you tried reproducing it other than AWS? The first code snippet looks like you've written your client to send logs to the fluentd's `forward` input plugin, right? What is the `msg` being sent from the client? Please add this to your question as well.

Comment: If you could add an [MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366988/what-does-mcve-mean) that would be helpful for others to reproduce it. Also, please add the fluentd's startup logs with `stdout`, and the input JSON message. Thanks! I'll try to dig into it and get back to you.